# Alternatives to decorator pattern on data object arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

Writing angular services, i found a pattern that i consider very convenient. I think it fits into the description of the *decorator* pattern. Given an array of objects:

```
players = [{
  name: 'Fred',
  counter: 0
},{
  name: 'Fritz',
  counter: 0
},{
  name: 'Frank',
  counter: 0
}];
```

Before passing it to views or controllers, i pass it through a decorate function:

```
players.forEach(decorate);
```

This function adds convenient methods to each object, allowing to change them in place without the need of retrieving the object index:

```
function decorate(p) {
  p.reset = function() {
    this.counter = 0;
  };
  p.increment = function() {
    this.counter += 1;
  };
  p.bonus = function() {
    this.counter += 10;
  };
  p.penalty = function() {
    this.counter -= 10;
  };
}
```

This is useful also without angular, but especially with angular it allows simple event binding within an `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="player in players">
  <div ng-click="player.reset()">reset {{player.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Considering also that services may be referenced by several controllers, simplifying the interface has quite an impact on the code at the end.

Let aside performance concerns, do you see any disadvantages in this approach? Or have you seen such a pattern under a different aspect (for example using `new`) that you consider better?

Comment: You could look into the [mixin](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) concept.

Comment: You could make performance better by using prototypes, i.e. `players = players.map(createInstance)`

Comment: Looks like the decorator pattern

Comment: yes indeed it looks similar to a decorator or mixin. i will take some time to study that terminology and edit the question in case

Answer (score 1):

In your controller I would have the different functions you need

```
.service("myService", function(){
    this.players = [...]
    this.reset = function(player){
        player.counter = 0;
    };
});

function MyController($scope, myService){
    $scope.players = myService.players;
    $scope.reset = function(player){
        myService.reset(player);
    }
    OR
    $scope.reset = myService.reset;
}
```

And then in your html just call that function instead

```
<div ng-repeat="player in players">
  <div ng-click="reset(player)">reset {{player.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting, but if the model lives in a service you want these functions to be defined in the same service for encapsulation, and in that case you will have to reassign them to a scope variable for every time that you want to use one of them in a controller

Comment: You could assign the service functions directly to the same scope, or have the scope call out to the service. Either way is fine. See my edit

Comment: Yes but this is exactly the type of duplication i wanted to avoid

Comment: Well, you somehow have to attach the service information to the scope you need. Perhaps $scope.myService = myService, then in your dome you can reference players.myService and myService.reset(player) ?